# How can I register 2 commands into 1

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft, bukkit

```
public class commandImp extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getCommand("impersonate").setExecutor(new commandImp());
        this.getCommand("imp").setExecutor(new commandImp());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            if (player.hasPermission("gate.imp")) {
                if (alias.equalsIgnoreCase("imp") || alias.equalsIgnoreCase("impersonate")) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "----- " + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "/impersonate" + ChatColor.GRAY + " -----");
...
```

My class file is called commandImp.class. This command works fine, but as you can see under the method `onEnable()`. I have registered 2 commands "impersonate" and "imp" (as an alias; shortened). I type /impersonate in-game and it works. But when I type /imp, it does not work.

How can I made them both work?

Answer (score 4):

Using the alias section for commands registered in the plugin.yml file allows for as many commands triggering the same command executor as you please. The format for this is as follows

```
commands:
    myCommand:
        aliases: [command, aliases, here]
```